# Skip whole folder/file in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a directory structure which look like this:

```
tests
    scenario01
        file.php
        something.js
    scenario02
        Test.phpt
    scenario03  
        Test.php
    Commands.php
    Something.php
```

When I run PHPUnit to test all the files in tests folder, it ends up with an error, that PHPT files are not supported for testing. I would REALLY like to keep the file ending with .phpt extension. Next, consider, that Test.php in scenario03 is also test, but I don't want to test it, because Commands.php is testing it's output.

I have tried testSuites in xml files, but it didn't help.

Comment: What's the reason for REALLY keeping the .phpt extension? Is there some dependency somewhere?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Well, the .phpt extension uses another testing framework and I need to ensure, that a test which will be executed (by the another testing framework) really returns what I expect. I pass some parameters and I need to know, that output from the test is correct. I temporary fixed it with renaming to .php and executing just one test, but still, I would appreciate to ignore it, because there may be some intentionally failing tests, which will serve as an another scenario.